# How to append to ul that have more than 4 items?

Tags: jquery

I want to add class and append something to `ul` that have more than 4 items. this is my code:

```js
$('ul.menu-odd').each(function() {
  if ($(this).children().length > 4) {
    $(this).addClass("two_cl");
    $('ul.menu-odd > li > a').append('<span class="badge menu_num" data-badge-caption="(1209)"></span>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Adding class works well and just do on `ul` that have more than 4 items. but it append my code to all the `a` tags. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please post your html as well.

Comment: $(this).find('li > a').append('<span class="badge menu_num" data-badge-caption="(1209)"></span>');, maybe? You should point to $(this) again....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `this` and `find` instead `ul.menu-odd`for the append function

```
$('ul.menu-odd').each(function() {

      var newSpan = '<span class="badge menu_num"' 
          newSpan += 'data-badge-caption="(1209)"></span>'

      if ($(this).children().length > 4) {
        $(this).addClass("two_cl");
        $(this).find('a').append(newSpan);

      }
    });
```